# Message Box if cell exceeds another cell with 2 table ranges

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Example]

I'm trying to set up an event wherein if a Cell in a specific Table exceeds the value of a Cell in another Table a MsgBox is displayed.
I've found the below code in another article which I can get to work:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("N1") Or Target = Range("R1") Then 'Only attempt to run the below code if target is a range you care about
        If Range("R1").Value2 <> Range("N1").Value2 Then
            MsgBox "Values differ"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

However, when I attempt to modify this to target the tables I am getting errors.
This is what I have come up with myself:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("Table1[Column1:ColumnX]") Or Target = Range("Table2[Column1:ColumnX]") Then
        If Range("Table1[Column1:ColumnX]")").Value2 > Range("Range("Table2[Column1:ColumnX]")").Value2 Then
            MsgBox "message txt"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

My Tables and Columns all have defined names, I have removed them for this post to hopefully make it easier to follow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've just realised while trying to fix this that it actually needs to be more complicated that originally posted.

I need to somehow include a lookup feature. For example, if "Name" in Table1:Column1 matches "Name" in Table2:Column1 and value of Table2:Column2 exceeds value of table1:column1 then display the message ... is this even possible?

Comment: This should only have one `Range`: `Range("Range("Table2[Column1:ColumnX]")").Value2`

Comment: It's definitely possible although I'm still not sure on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you JMP, I will give that a try shortly.

Comment: @JoshL, I've added a pic which will hopefully help. Essentially what I am trying to achieve is stopping someone from adding a valuer in Table 2 (E3) that is greater than Table 1 (A3) using the Name as a reference point.
Having a msgBox will just help keep users aware of what they can/can't do, I've also tried Data Validation to achieve the same thing.

hope this helps clear things up.

Comment: `If Target = Range("N1")` means `If Target.Value = Range("N1").Value`. It does *not* answer the question "Is Target the range N1?".

Comment: Thank you to all that offered some help, I have tried both methods and although I can get them to work the moment I start using defined Table names rather than Cell ranges everything falls apart.

I am clearly way out of my depth on what I am trying to do and am going to look at an alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate data, use [Data validation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249).

Select the input range, i.e. E3:E4 on your screenshot.
<kbd>`Data`</kbd> <kbd>`->`</kbd> <kbd>`Data Validation`</kbd>.
Allow: Custom. Formula: `=$E3<=VLOOKUP($D3,$A$3:$B$4,2,FALSE)`.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get this to work for the whole table in one Sub but if you were ok with using 2 subs you could use the following.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Range("B3") Or Target = Range("E3") Then

If Range("E3").Value2 > Range("B3").Value2 Then

MsgBox "Values in Table 2 must be less than values in Table 1"

End If

End If


End Sub
```

.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Range("B4") Or Target = Range("E4") Then

If Range("E4").Value2 > Range("B4").Value2 Then

MsgBox "Values in Table 2 must be less than values in Table 1"

End If

End If
End Sub
```